# Using graphql-codegen adds query to query?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to use graphql-codegen to add types to my graphql queries

I have this in my package.json

```
"@graphql-codegen/add": "^3.1.0",
"@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.3.0",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.2.1",
"@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^3.2.2",
```

I have a codegen.yml

```
overwrite: true
schema: http://localhost:3000/api/graphql
documents: 'queries/*.ts'

generates:
  generated/index.tsx:

    config:
      reactApolloVersion: 3
      withHooks: false
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

I'm using keystonejs which has a graphql api

My query is like

```
export const ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY = gql`
    query ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY{
    allProducts{
        id
        price
        description
        name
        photo{
        id
        image{
            publicUrlTransformed
        }
        }
    }
    }
`
```

And in my package.json I have

```
"codegen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
```

If I run `yarn codegen` I get the types generated in `generated/index.tsx`

For `ALL_PRODUCTS_QUERY` I get

```
export type All_Products_QueryQuery = { __typename?: 'Query', allProducts?: Array<{ __typename?: 'Product', id: string, price?: number | null | undefined, description?: string | null | undefined, name?: string | null | undefined, photo?: { __typename?: 'ProductImage', id: string, image?: { __typename?: 'CloudinaryImage_File', publicUrlTransformed?: string | null | undefined } | null | undefined } | null | undefined } | null | undefined> | null | undefined };
```

Why does the Query get added to the name so its now `All_Products_QueryQuery` and why is it not an interface

I thought it would be an interface to describe the query